# Unable to type AM/PM in masked time control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik

Using the telerik control as in the picture below playing with their demo website:

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#MaskedInput/MaskedDateTimeInput

[image]

It acts weird, I cannot type AM or PM, I need to set some sort of mask that allows me to also "TYPE" the AM or PM the same way I type its time section with keyboard.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the mask to `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` includes the AM/PM part. You don't appear to be able to type AM or PM however using the cursor keys you can switch between the two.